# Issues inserting unsigned char array into database

Tags: mysql, c, linux, types

Here's my code. It is supposed to do 254 ARP requests and store the ip and mac addresses into an unsigned char array, and after that store them into a data base. It all seems to work perfect except the database part. It i only storing the first value correctly (the counter value) but not the arrays. I have tried passing them as %u, %X but these formats expect unsigned ints but no unsigned char arrays. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netpacket/packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <mysql.h>



unsigned char macOrigen[6];
unsigned char ipOrigen[4];
unsigned char ipDestino[4];
unsigned char tramaEnviar[1514];
unsigned char tramaRecibir[1514];
unsigned char mascaraSubred[4];
unsigned char ipDestino[4];
unsigned char respuestaArp[2] = {0x00, 0x02};
unsigned char protocolo[2] = {0x08, 0x00};
unsigned char ethertype[2] = {0x08, 0x06};
unsigned char macDestino[6] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
unsigned char macBroadcast[6] = {0XFF, 0XFF, 0XFF, 0XFF, 0XFF, 0XFF};
unsigned char hardware[1] = {0x01};
unsigned char longitudHW[1] = {0x06};
unsigned char longitudIP[1] = {0x04};
unsigned char codigoOperacionSolicitud[2] = {0x00, 0x01};

int ObtenerDatos (int packetSocket){
    char nombre[10];
    int index;
    struct ifreq interfaz;
    printf("Ingrese el nombre de la interfaz:\nPuede consultar las inerfaces disponibles tecleando 'ifconfig' en otra terminal.\n\n");
    gets(nombre);
    strcpy(interfaz.ifr_name, nombre);
    if(ioctl(packetSocket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &interfaz) == -1){
        perror("Error al obener el índice.\n");
        }else{
            index = interfaz.ifr_ifindex;
        }
    if(ioctl(packetSocket, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &interfaz) == -1)
    {
        perror("No se ha podido obtener la informacion del dispositivo.\n");
    }else{
        memcpy(macOrigen, interfaz.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, 6);      
    }
    if(ioctl(packetSocket, SIOCGIFADDR, &interfaz) == -1){
        perror("No se ha podido obtener la informacion del dispositivo.\n");
    }else{
        memcpy(ipOrigen, interfaz.ifr_addr.sa_data+2, 4);
    }if(ioctl(packetSocket, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &interfaz) == -1){
        perror("Error al obtener la mascara de subred.\n");
    }else{
        memcpy(mascaraSubred, interfaz.ifr_netmask.sa_data+2, 4);
    }

    return index;
}

void estructuraTramaArp(unsigned char *tramaEnviar){
    memcpy(tramaEnviar, macBroadcast, 6);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+6, macOrigen, 6);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+12, ethertype, 2);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+14, hardware, 1);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+15, protocolo, 2);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+17, longitudHW, 1);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+18, longitudIP, 1);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+19, longitudIP, 1);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+20, codigoOperacionSolicitud, 2);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+22, macOrigen, 6);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+28, ipOrigen, 4);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+32, macBroadcast, 6);
    memcpy(tramaEnviar+38, ipDestino, 4);
}

void solicitudArp(int packetSocket, unsigned char *tramaEnviar, int index){
    int tam;
    struct sockaddr_ll nic;
    memset(&nic, 0x00, sizeof(nic));
    nic.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    nic.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    nic.sll_ifindex = index;
    tam = sendto(packetSocket, tramaEnviar, 60, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&nic, sizeof(nic));
    if (tam == -1){
        perror("Error al enviar la solicitud ARP");

    }else("Exito al enviar la trama");
}

void recibeTramasArp(int packetSocket, unsigned char *tramaRecibir, int longitud){

    struct timeval tiempoEspera;
    tiempoEspera.tv_sec = 0;
    tiempoEspera.tv_usec = 900000L;
    int tam, res, i, j;
    fd_set lectura, escritura; 
    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&lectura);
        FD_SET(packetSocket, &escritura);
        if((res=select(packetSocket+1, &lectura, NULL, NULL, &tiempoEspera)) > 0)
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(packetSocket, &lectura)){
                if((tam = recvfrom(packetSocket, tramaRecibir, longitud, 0, NULL, 0)) < 0){
                    perror("Error al recibir.\n");
                    break;
                    }else{
                        if(!memcmp(tramaRecibir+0, macOrigen, 6) && !memcmp(tramaRecibir+12,ethertype, 2) && !memcmp(tramaRecibir+16,protocolo,2) && !memcmp(tramaRecibir+20,respuestaArp,2) && !memcmp(tramaRecibir+28,ipDestino,4) && !memcmp(tramaRecibir+38,ipOrigen,4) ){
        printf("La dirección IP:\n");
        for(i = 28; i <= 31; i++){
        printf("%.2d:",tramaRecibir[i]);
        }
        printf("\nRespondio con la direccion mac:\n");
        for(j = 22; j <=27; j++){
            printf("%.2x.",tramaRecibir[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        break;

}
    printf("No se recibio respuesta.\n");
}
}
    break;
}else{
    printf("\nEl tiempo de espera se agoto.\n\n");
    break;  
}

}

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int indice, i, j; 
    char stmt_buf[100];
    char bd [100];
    int packetSocket = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    MYSQL *con = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (con == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", mysql_error(con));

    }
    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "angel", "xmdapoe", "arp", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    }
    if (mysql_query(con, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS info"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    }   
    if (mysql_query(con, "CREATE TABLE info(id INT, ip TEXT, mac TEXT)"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(con));
    }
    if (packetSocket == -1)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el socket.\n");
    }else{
        indice = ObtenerDatos(packetSocket);
        memcpy(ipDestino, ipOrigen, 4);
            ipDestino[3] = 1;
        for(i = 0; i<254 ; i++){
            printf("Direccion IP destino:");
            printf("\n");
            for (j = 0; j<4; j++){
                printf("%d.",ipDestino[j]);
                }   
                estructuraTramaArp(tramaEnviar);
                solicitudArp(packetSocket, tramaEnviar, indice);
                recibeTramasArp(packetSocket, tramaRecibir, 1514);
                sprintf(stmt_buf, "insert into info values ('%d', '%.2x', '%.2x')", i, ipOrigen,macOrigen);
                if(mysql_query(con, stmt_buf)){
                    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",mysql_error(con));               
                }
                ipDestino[3]++;
            }
            }
    close(packetSocket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With sprintf using %.2x you are just printing the ipOrigen's and macOrigen's memory addresses.
I think that what you want may be achievable with:

```
    sprintf (buf, "%d%d%d%d", ipOrigen[0], ipOrigen[1], ipOrigen[2], ipOrigen[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your sprintf statement, you're actually printing the address of the first element of ipOrigen and macOrigen arrays. For ipOrigen you can do something like:

```
printf("%x", htonl(*(uint32_t *)ipOrigen));
```

For macOrigen you could use a similar approach by using htobe64() from endian.h.